# Using jQuery, count the number of immediate div's under a parent

Tags: jquery, count, element

I have a situation like this - When a link is clicked (i.e.,Click1, Click2 etc), I want to get the count (number) of the immediate div's under "tracker". In this example, the number of div's under first "tracker" is 3 and under second tracker, it is 2. So, if I click on (say) Click2, it should alert 3. I am always getting 1.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".connect", function(ev) {
  console.log($(this).parents(".tracker > div.item").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="tracker">
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click1</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click2</a></div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click3</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tracker">
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click4</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click5</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should consider using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) rather than `.parents()`.  In this case, it's no different, but if you were to do `.parents("div")` (for example) it could give a very different result

Answer (score 3):

You're using a selector for the parent that includes its child element. That won't get you the right parent. Select the correct ancestor first, then the children.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".connect", function(ev) {
  console.log($(this).parents(".tracker").children('.item').length);

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.clear();
  }, 800);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="tracker">
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click1</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click2</a></div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click3</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tracker">
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click4</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="#" class="connect">Click5</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As an alternative, to adapt OPs attempt: `.parents(".tracker").find(">div.item")` (not going to check if one is more efficient than the other, it's just an alternative method)

Comment: I considered that initially, but find the syntax slightly less intuitive. YMMV